# CDVViewController still executing JS after parent has been removed

Tags: objective-c, ios, webview, automatic-ref-counting, cordova

I have attempted to insert a Cordova CleaverView (CDVViewController) into a UIViewController(SenchaViewController) instantiated from a storyboard in order to render a javascript Sencha based view.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

if (![ self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];    
}   

self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


CDVViewController *cdvc = [CDVViewController new];

cdvc.wwwFolderName = @"www";
cdvc.startPage = @"sencha.html";
cdvc.useSplashScreen = NO;


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
    cdvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
} else {
    cdvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
} 

[self.view addSubview:cdvc.view];
[self.view  bringSubviewToFront:self.menuButton];
[self.view  bringSubviewToFront:self.favButton];
cdvc = nil;

NSString *jsSetIdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fetchGuid = function(){return '%@';}", [player valueForKey:@"playerID"]]; 
[[cdvc webView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsSetIdString];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];
```

}

My problem is after I remove the parent ViewController(SenchaViewController) which owns the CDVViewController's view instance, the CDVViewController does not get released and is still running in the background as I can still see javascript logging in the console. The causes for me to have several CDVViewController all running at once.

This is how the app adds the Parent View Controller:

```
- (void)renderPlayer:(NSNotification*)notification {
SenchaViewController* newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SenchaView"];
NSDictionary *player = notification.object;

// Set active player
if( player != nil && [player valueForKey:@"playerID"] != @"" ){        
    // Attach Player Dictionary to Sencha View
    newTopViewController.player = player;

    // Send it to the top
    CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
}
```

This is how the Parent View controller which owns the CDVController is being removed

```
_topViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[_topViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[_topViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Am I missing something? I was assuming ARC would dealloc this for me

Answer (score 0):

Cordova has some dirty aspects, and this is one of them. Removing a CDVViewController is not enough to get it released. You have to also call the [controller dispose] method.